# Limit of an Integral, Then taking Sum

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

I am given that $I_n=\int^1_0x^ne^x\,dx$

Now, how can I find the value of the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{I_{k+1}}{k}\right)$$

I suppose solving for $I_n$ is that necessary first here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you are right about the first step.

First of all, let us find the recurrent relation for the $I_n$.

Integrating by parts we get:
$$I_n=\int^1_0x^ne^x\,dx=e-\int^1_0nx^{n-1}e^x\,dx=e-nI_{n-1}$$
This is equivalent to $I_n+nI_{n-1}=e$. The last equality implies $I_{n+1}+(n+1)I_n=I_n+nI_{n-1}$ or $I_{n+1}=n(I_{n-1}-I_n)$. Now lets analyze our sum.

We obtain:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{I_{k+1}}{k}=\sum_{k=2}^n(I_{k-1}-I_k)+I_2=I_1-I_n+I_2$$
Now we must find to which number does $I_n$ tend.

It's quite simple to note that:
$$0\leq \int^1_0x^ne^x\,dx \leq e\int^1_0x^n\,dx\Leftrightarrow 0\leq I_n\leq \frac{e}{n+1}$$
So we get that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=0$$

To finish our problem, we must integrate by parts to calculate that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(I_1+I_2-I_n\right)=I_1+I_2=e-1$$

Comment: Another excellent solution!  +1

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{I_{k+1}}{k}\right)
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{k+1}}{k} \right) e^x \, \mathrm{d}x
\\&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \left( -x \log(1-x) + d_{n+1}(x) \right) e^x \,\mathrm{d}x
\\&= \int_0^1 -x \log(1-x) e^x \, \mathrm{d}x
+ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 d_{n+1}(x) e^x \mathrm{d}x
\\&= \int_0^1 -x \log(1-x) e^x \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$

where $d_n(x)$ is the error term for the $n$-th order Taylor series for $-x \log(1-x)$. All that remains is to show that that last integral is $e-1$ (the integrand has an elementary antiderivative) and to show the last limit really does converge to zero; e.g. by bounding the error term. (note that it's an improper integral) (also note that it's not enough to observe $d_{n+1}(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, because the limit is outside the integral, not inside)

This may not be an easier way, but I did want to show that you didn't *have* to find $I_{k+1}$ first.

Comment: This is the way I would have gone.  You might want to state the justification for interchanging operations in the next to last line of equalities.  Otherwise, well done!  +1

Comment: @Dr: I didn't think distributing $\int$ over $+$ needed comment, or did I overlook something? I suppose maybe it's worth pointing out that you can do that if two of the three integrals involved exist. (and if so the third must exist too)

Comment: Actually, it is the interchange of the limit with the integral that needs to be justified.

Comment: @Dr. I didn't interchange limit with integral: after breaking the integral into two pieces, the first piece is constant with respect to $n$.

Comment: And the second piece is not.

Comment: @Dr.: ... and I didn't interchange them for the second piece. I think I see what you're trying to get at, though: it's worth explicitly commenting that it's not enough to say limit vanishes because $d_{n+1}(x) \to 0$.

Comment: Yes.  The second term vanishes ... but why?  I assumed that you used UC of DC to interchange operations.  But it sounds as if you had something else in mind.  And that might definitely be worth sharing.

Comment: Excuse me, $\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{x^{k+1}}{x}=-xln(1-x)$. There is an exactly $=$ in my textbook. So why we do need the error term as $n\to\infty$

Comment: @Rowan: Because the sum only goes up to $k=n$.